# OpenSSL and Network namespace - Closed

Tags: c, linux, networking, ssl, openssl

I am developing an application using OpenSSL library. I am new to OpenSSL library. My application was working correctly until I tested it within network namespace. My application hangs at SSL_Connect. I am using sockets in the blocking mode. I read somewhere that I should use non-blocking mode instead to solve the issue. So I switched from blocking sockets to non-blocking sockets but my code still gets stuck at SSL_Connect method in the client.

I just have a simple client-server program nothing fancy stuff. I have added SSL methods inside them to make them secure. Everything works perfectly when I run them inside terminal but when I switch to network namespace and run inside virtual network, the client code hangs at SSL_Connect. I am not able to understand what may be causing this problem. Any help will be appreciated!

Here is the code for server.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define SERVER_PORT  12345

#define TRUE             1
#define FALSE            0

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int    i, len, rc, on = 1;
   int    listen_sd, max_sd, new_sd;
   int    desc_ready, end_server = FALSE;
   int    close_conn;
   char   buffer[80];
   struct sockaddr_in   addr;
   struct timeval       timeout;
   fd_set        master_set, working_set;
   char ch='a';

    //ssl initiation
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    ERR_load_SSL_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_METHOD *meth = SSLv3_server_method();
    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "TrustStore.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "privatekey.key", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Create an AF_INET stream socket to receive incoming       */
   /* connections on                                            */
   /*************************************************************/
   listen_sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (listen_sd < 0)
   {
      perror("socket() failed");
      exit(-1);
   }

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Allow socket descriptor to be reuseable                   */
   /*************************************************************/
   rc = setsockopt(listen_sd, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,
                   (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
   if (rc < 0)
   {
      perror("setsockopt() failed");
      close(listen_sd);
      exit(-1);
   }

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Set socket to be non-blocking.  All of the sockets for    */
   /* the incoming connections will also be non-blocking since  */
   /* they will inherit that state from the listening socket.   */
   /*************************************************************/
   rc = ioctl(listen_sd, FIONBIO, (char *)&on);
   if (rc < 0)
   {
      perror("ioctl() failed");
      close(listen_sd);
      exit(-1);
   }

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Bind the socket                                           */
   /*************************************************************/
   memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
   addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   addr.sin_port        = htons(SERVER_PORT);
   rc = bind(listen_sd,
             (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
   if (rc < 0)
   {
      perror("bind() failed");
      close(listen_sd);
      exit(-1);
   }

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Set the listen back log                                   */
   /*************************************************************/
   rc = listen(listen_sd, 32);
   if (rc < 0)
   {
      perror("listen() failed");
      close(listen_sd);
      exit(-1);
   }

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Initialize the master fd_set                              */
   /*************************************************************/
   FD_ZERO(&master_set);
   max_sd = listen_sd;
   FD_SET(listen_sd, &master_set);

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Initialize the timeval struct to 3 minutes.  If no        */
   /* activity after 3 minutes this program will end.           */
   /*************************************************************/
   timeout.tv_sec  = 3 * 60;
   timeout.tv_usec = 0;

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Loop waiting for incoming connects or for incoming data   */
   /* on any of the connected sockets.                          */
   /*************************************************************/
   do
   {
      /**********************************************************/
      /* Copy the master fd_set over to the working fd_set.     */
      /**********************************************************/
      memcpy(&working_set, &master_set, sizeof(master_set));

      /**********************************************************/
      /* Call select() and wait 5 minutes for it to complete.   */
      /**********************************************************/
      printf("Waiting on select()...\n");
      rc = select(max_sd + 1, &working_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

      /**********************************************************/
      /* Check to see if the select call failed.                */
      /**********************************************************/
      if (rc < 0)
      {
         perror("  select() failed");
         break;
      }

      /**********************************************************/
      /* Check to see if the 5 minute time out expired.         */
      /**********************************************************/
      if (rc == 0)
      {
         printf("  select() timed out.  End program.\n");
         break;
      }

      /**********************************************************/
      /* One or more descriptors are readable.  Need to         */
      /* determine which ones they are.                         */
      /**********************************************************/
      desc_ready = rc;
      for (i=0; i <= max_sd  &&  desc_ready > 0; ++i)
      {
         /*******************************************************/
         /* Check to see if this descriptor is ready            */
         /*******************************************************/
         if (FD_ISSET(i, &working_set))
         {
            /****************************************************/
            /* A descriptor was found that was readable - one   */
            /* less has to be looked for.  This is being done   */
            /* so that we can stop looking at the working set   */
            /* once we have found all of the descriptors that   */
            /* were ready.                                      */
            /****************************************************/
            desc_ready -= 1;

            /****************************************************/
            /* Check to see if this is the listening socket     */
            /****************************************************/
            if (i == listen_sd)
            {
               printf("  Listening socket is readable\n");
               /*************************************************/
               /* Accept all incoming connections that are      */
               /* queued up on the listening socket before we   */
               /* loop back and call select again.              */
               /*************************************************/
               do
               {
                  /**********************************************/
                  /* Accept each incoming connection.  If       */
                  /* accept fails with EWOULDBLOCK, then we     */
                  /* have accepted all of them.  Any other      */
                  /* failure on accept will cause us to end the */
                  /* server.                                    */
                  /**********************************************/
                  new_sd = accept(listen_sd, NULL, NULL);
                  if (new_sd < 0)
                  {
                     if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                     {
                        perror("  accept() failed");
                        end_server = TRUE;
                     }
                     break;
                  }

                  /**********************************************/
                  /* Add the new incoming connection to the     */
                  /* master read set                            */
                  /**********************************************/
                  printf("  New incoming connection - %d\n", new_sd);
                  FD_SET(new_sd, &master_set);
                  if (new_sd > max_sd)
                     max_sd = new_sd;

                  /**********************************************/
                  /* Loop back up and accept another incoming   */
                  /* connection                                 */
                  /**********************************************/
               } while (new_sd != -1);
            }

            /****************************************************/
            /* This is not the listening socket, therefore an   */
            /* existing connection must be readable             */
            /****************************************************/
            else
            {
               printf("  Descriptor %d is readable\n", i);
               close_conn = FALSE;

SSL* ssl;
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, i);

//handshake

SSL_accept(ssl);
printf("\nHandshake Done\n");

int result = SSL_read(ssl, &ch, sizeof(ch));

if(result<0)
{
    printf("\nreading Error");
}
++ch;
result = SSL_write(ssl, &ch, sizeof(ch));


if(result<0)
{
    printf("\nwriting Error");
}
               /*************************************************/
               /* If the close_conn flag was turned on, we need */
               /* to clean up this active connection.  This     */
               /* clean up process includes removing the        */
               /* descriptor from the master set and            */
               /* determining the new maximum descriptor value  */
               /* based on the bits that are still turned on in */
               /* the master set.                               */
               /*************************************************/
               if (close_conn)
               {
                  close(i);
                  FD_CLR(i, &master_set);
                  if (i == max_sd)
                  {
                     while (FD_ISSET(max_sd, &master_set) == FALSE)
                        max_sd -= 1;
                  }
               }
            } /* End of existing connection is readable */
         } /* End of if (FD_ISSET(i, &working_set)) */
      } /* End of loop through selectable descriptors */

   } while (end_server == FALSE);

   /*************************************************************/
   /* Cleanup all of the sockets that are open                  */
   /*************************************************************/
   for (i=0; i <= max_sd; ++i)
   {
      if (FD_ISSET(i, &master_set))
         close(i);
   }
}
```

Here is the code for client.c file:

```
/**************************************************************************/
/* Generic client example is used with connection-oriented server designs */
/**************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


#define SERVER_PORT  12345

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int    len, rc;
   int    sockfd;
   char   send_buf[80];
   char   recv_buf[80];
   struct sockaddr_in   addr;
   char ch = 'A';
   int result;


    //ssl initiation
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    ERR_load_SSL_strings();
    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_METHOD *meth;
    meth = SSLv3_client_method();
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL* ssl;
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);    
    result = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "TrustStore1.pem", 0);
    printf("\nCA load result = %d\n", result);
    printf("\nSSL initialized");

   /*************************************************/
   /* Create an AF_INET stream socket               */
   /*************************************************/
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sockfd < 0)
   {
      perror("socket");
      exit(-1);
   }

   /*************************************************/
   /* Initialize the socket address structure       */
   /*************************************************/
   memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
   addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.1");
   addr.sin_port        = htons(SERVER_PORT);

   /*************************************************/
   /* Connect to the server                         */
   /*************************************************/
   rc = connect(sockfd,
                (struct sockaddr *)&addr,
                sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
   if (rc < 0)
   {
      perror("connect");
      close(sockfd);
      exit(-1);
   }
   printf("Connect completed.\n");
   //ssl-ing the connection
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    BIO *sbio;
    sbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_socket());
    BIO_set_fd(sbio, sockfd, BIO_CLOSE);
    SSL_set_bio(ssl, sbio, sbio);
    //SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 1);
    //SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
    printf("Before SSL_connect: %d\n", result);
    result = SSL_connect(ssl);
    printf("SSL_connect: %d\n", result);

    if(SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl)!=NULL)
    {


        //check cert
        //check_cert(ssl);
        //getting the CA certificate



        //_ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);


        int result_long = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
        printf("\nCertificate Check Result: %d", result_long);
        if (SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) != X509_V_OK)
            {
                printf("\nCertiticate Verification Failed\n");
                return 0;
                //exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nCertiticate Verification Succeeded");
            }

    }

    SSL_write(ssl, &ch, 1);
    SSL_read(ssl, &ch, 1);
    printf("char from server = %c\n", ch);
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);  

   /*************************************************/
   /* Close down the socket                         */
   /*************************************************/
   close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your network namespace is configured properly? Can `wget` reach the same server? Can you reach non-SSL servers? I don't have any experience with network namespace, so you will need to debug that yourself, or find someone with network namespace experience.

Comment: Yes network namespace is configured properly. My normal application runs without any flaw.

Comment: I would still proceed with normal network debugging process. Use a packet trace utility (e.g., wireshark), observe your SSL application on terminal what the trace looks like, then observe in the network namespace, and see what the differences are.

Comment: I finally solved the issue. I made sever non-blocking but I did not make client non-blocking. After making client non-blocking, I was able to run code successfully.